# Get Hosting Environment by means of ConfiguratonBuilder?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core project I rely on the command line arguments to override the default url and to override the environment setting.

> dotnet watch run --server.urls=https://localhost:5001 --environment "Localhost"

I use the CommandLineConfigurationExtensions to add the `args` to the ConfigurationBuilder. This works fine, but I would also like to use the built Configuration

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        // More stuff happens with WebHostBuilder,
        // and I would very much like to check the
        // environment here.
    }
}
```

I would like to access the same environment settings that are available through the `IHostingEnvironment env` parameter in the `Configure()` method of the `Startup` class. But I want to do it in `Main()`

I realize I *could* just parse the command line arguments and look for the value myself, or pull the appropriate value from the `configuration` variable I just built. However, it seems inelegant when there is obviously exists a standardized method for this in whatever part of the framework that magically instantiates the class implementing the `IHostingEnvironment` interface for the rest of us to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may directly use `config["environment"]` or if it is not specified, set `Hosting.EnvironmentName.Production` as the default value.

Let me explain why.

If you look into `IHostingEnvironment` [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingEnvironment.cs), you will see that `EnvironmentName` is a simple property with public getter/setter and by default, it contains the `Production` value:

```
public class HostingEnvironment : IHostingEnvironment
{
    public string EnvironmentName { get; set; } = Hosting.EnvironmentName.Production;
    ...
}
```

Then value may be changed when `Initialize` [extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs) is called. Using data from `WebHostOptions option`:

```
hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName =
   options.Environment ??
   hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
```

To be more specific, the `option.Environment` property [is used](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHostOptions.cs#L26), that is

```
public WebHostOptions(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    ...
    Environment = configuration[WebHostDefaults.EnvironmentKey];
    ...
}
```

where `WebHostDefaults.EnvironmentKey` is

```
public static class WebHostDefaults
{
    public static readonly string EnvironmentKey = "environment";
}
```

So `environment` key is used from config source to specify hosting Environment.

Comment: As long as `config["environment"]` "merges" in to set the current environment, I'm happy with using it. Thanks for the insight! It has provided me with much needed confidence :)